# Using the author names and ampersand symbol (&) instead of the words "et al." in the text for style apa

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, ampersand

I want to use the author names and ampersand symbols (&) instead of the word "and" in text for style apa, so e.g.

```
Maji, Biswas & Roy (2001) instead of Maji et al. (2001)
```

and

```
(Maji, Biswas & Roy,2001) instead of (Maji et al., 2001)
```

In my `apalike.bst` file, the `format.lab.names` function is as follows:

```
    FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  s num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$ " et~al." * }
    { #2 <
    'skip$
    { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
        { " et~al." * }
        { " \& " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
      if$
    }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

How can I do what I want from this part?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you consider using `biblatex-apa`?

Comment: The `apalike` bibliography style more than 30 years old and (probably unsurprisingly) no longer implements the "latest" APA formatting guidelines. If your objective is to conform to the APA6 citation call-out guidelines, you should load the `apacite` package along with the `apacite` bibliography style. If you pursue the `apacite` route, you won't have to fiddle to get the `&` conjunction particles.

Answer (score 3):

Let me start by observing that your proposed formatting objective does NOT adhere to current APA standards for citation call-outs. First, the `&` symbol should be used for "parenthetic" citation call-outs (and for the formatted entries), but for some reason **NOT** for "text-style" citation call-outs. For the latter type of citation call-outs, the conjunction to be used continues to be `and`. Second, for the second and all further instances of a citation call-out of a piece with three or more authors, one is most definitely supposed to use `et al`, rather than keep repeating the full list of names.

Next, the `apalike` bibliography style is about 35 years old by now and, as such, does not reflect current APA requirements for the formatting of citation call-outs and bibliographic items. Rather than pointlessly tinker with the positively ancient `apalike` bibliography style, you'd be much better off loading the `apacite` bibliography style along with the `apacite` citation management package.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{abr01,
   author = "P. K. Maji and R. Biswas and A. R. Roy",
   title  = "Intuitionistic fuzzy soft sets",
   journal= "The Journal of Fuzzy Mathematics",
   year   = 2001,
   volume = 9,
   number = 3,
   pages  = "677--692",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} % to enable '\citet' and '\citep' macros
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\citet{abr01}, \citet{abr01}

\citep*{abr01}, \citep{abr01}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```